# tags in JS and css counter increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="form">

      <ul class="tab-group">
     <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard</a></li>
     <li class="tab"><a href="#login">MedalTally</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="signup">

      <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

        <ol>
       <li>
         <mark>Shivam Sharma</mark>
         <small>315</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Deepa B</mark>
         <small>301</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
         <small>292</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
         <small>245</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
         <small>203</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
         <small>203</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
         <small>245</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
         <small>203</small>
       </li>

        </ol>
      </div>


     
        </div>

     <div id="login">

     </div>

     </div><!-- tab-content -->

    </div>
     <!-- /form -->




    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>



  </body>
</html>
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1ab188;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

a:hover {
  color: #179b77;
}

.form {
  background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin: 40px auto;


}

.tab-group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tab-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.tab-group li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a0b3b0;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;

  transition: .5s ease;
}

.tab-group li a:hover {
  background: #179b77;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-group .active a {
  background: #1ab188;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}


/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/

body {
  min-height: 650px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background:-webkit-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #f39264 0%, #f2606f 100%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding 10px;
}


/*--------------------
Leaderboard
--------------------*/

.leaderboard {


  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;

  display: none;
}


.leaderboard ol li {
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  counter-increment: leaderboard;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}

.leaderboard ol li::before {
  content: counter(leaderboard);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #c24448;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.leaderboard ol li mark {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 350%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px 18px 50px;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.leaderboard ol li mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li mark::after {

  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;

  left: 9px;
  border-top: 10px solid #c24448;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.leaderboard ol li mark::after {
  left: auto;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.leaderboard ol li small {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.leaderboard ol li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fa6855;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1) {
  background: #fa6855;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(1)::after {
  background: #fa6855;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #e0574f;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2)::after {
  background: #e0574f;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(2) mark::after {
  border-top: 6px solid #ba4741;
  bottom: -7px;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) {
  background: #d7514d;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3)::after {
  background: #d7514d;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(3) mark::after {
  border-top: 2px solid #b0433f;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(6) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) {
  background: #cd4b4b;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7)::after {
  background: #cd4b4b;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(7) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(4) mark::after {
  top: -7px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #a63d3d;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) {
  background: #c24448;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8)::after {
  background: #c24448;
  box-shadow: 0 -2.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(8) mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:nth-child(5) mark::after {
  top: -9px;
  bottom: auto;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #993639;
}

.leaderboard ol li:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: visible;
}

.leaderboard ol li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
  transform: scaleX(1.06) scaleY(1.03);
}

.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::before,
.leaderboard ol li:hover mark::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="form">

      <ul class="tab-group">
     <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">RecentWeek</a></li>
     <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Overall</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="signup">

      <div class="leaderboard" id="leaderboard">

        <ol>
       <li>
         <mark>Mustaque Rashid</mark>
         <small>315</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Deepa Balasubramaniam</mark>
         <small>301</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Raymond Knight</mark>
         <small>292</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
         <small>245</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
         <small>203</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
         <small>203</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Trevor McCormick</mark>
         <small>245</small>
       </li>
       <li>
         <mark>Andrew Fox</mark>
         <small>203</small>
       </li>

        </ol>
      </div>


     
        </div>

     <div id="login">

     </div>

     </div><!-- tab-content -->

    </div>
     <!-- /form -->




    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>



  </body>
</html>
```

[image: current situation]

I have the above codes for the html ,css and js for a leaderboard .

Issue:
1.how can we get rid of the incremental counter in the left side of the leaderboard   body.

2.how can we display the leaderboard as soon as the page loads ,not just the tags i.e. not just the leaderboard and medaltally tags.

3.how to include  two more tags below the above tags i.e below the leaderboard and medaltally.

Fiddle link for the above codes : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Zedhmem/ju0xr8of/1/)

Comment: For your first issue, remove `counter-increment: leaderboard;` and `content: counter(leaderboard);`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.But I want to get rid of the counter-increment on the extreme left in the black background not from within the leaderboard.@AndreiV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue. Add the following property into the `.leaderboard ol li` class

```
    list-style: none;
```

For your second request replace the onclick jquery event handler code and replace it with the following inside the document.ready block

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var _this = $('.tab a:first')
                var block = _this.attr('href');
                if(block == "#leaderboard"){
                    $(block).fadeIn();
                    $('#login').hide();
                    // code to hide other tabs if added
                }
        });
```

For the 3 request: add 2 more li tags in the `<ul class="tab-group">` as follows

```
<ul class="tab-group">
  <li class="tab active"><a href="#leaderboard">LeaderBoard</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#login">MedalTally</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">Third Tag</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">Forth Tag</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

[Edit]

For css to look good do the follow:

1. add `padding:0px !important;` property in the `.leaderboard ol` class
2. remove the `height: 308px;` from the `.leaderboard` class.

Comment: Thank you so much.You a genius.God Bless .

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('.tab a').on('click',function(e){
                var _this = $('.tab a:first')
                var block = _this.attr('href');
                if(block == "#leaderboard"){
                    $(block).fadeIn();
                    $('#login').hide();
                    // code to hide other tabs if added
                }
                if(block == "#login"){
                  $(block).fadeIn();
                  $('#leaderboard').hide();
                }
  });
        });

Comment: I want the first tag to hide after clicking the second and its content to be displayed.where exactly am I making the mistake in the above code ? @Nasir

Comment: I mean the first tab's content to hide and the second tag 's content to show up as I click the second tab